# Files marked as readonly during build

Tags: tfs, biztalk, biztalk-2009

It seems that when TFS does a build, when it creates the build directory and pulls the files down from source, it is marking all the source files as read only. This is causing a problem with a BizTalk solution that we have, it looks like at build time biztalk generates/edits a cs class for mapping files, and this is the same type of file that gets and unauthorized access exception during the build if it is marked as readonly. But for the life of me, and cannot figure out how to change this behavior of the TFS. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The files are marked readonly, because it is doing a get latest version from TFS. If BizTalk is generating a file during compilation, you can either not include this file in Source Control, or you can remove the readonly flag of that file.

You can remove the flag in TFS 2010 by editing the Build Process Template and add an InvokeProcess activity to execute the attrib -r command.

For more information how to add the InvokeProcess to the build process template see http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/27/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-2-Add-arguments-and-variables.aspx

Comment: I am using TFS2013 update 4 and VS2013 update4. I am using an unchanged DefaultTemplate.xaml build template. I don't have any .xsd.cs files checked in. My experience is that the TFS build agent is marking the folder as read only which prevents the xsd.cs being created as part of the build, this causes the build to fail. If I remove the read-only flag from the folder then I am able to manually run a successful build on the build server - but this flag is added back during the following automated build.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal behaviour. But if you have some automatically generated (i.e. minification/grunt ...) processes that require writable files, update your project file and make each file writable in a prebuild process.

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<Exec Command=“attrib -R $(SolutionRoot)\myFile.ext“ />
</Target>
```

I know its late, but hope this will help someone come here.

Reference from:
https://benoit808.wordpress.com/2007/10/30/changing-a-files-attribute-from-a-msbuild-script/

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT check-in the .cs files into Source Control for a biztalk project.  Go to those files in Source Control and delete them.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I checked my local files and they were with READ-ONLY attribute, so I removed the attribute locally, checked-in the files again and it all works :